# Rails page reload - How do I control the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page in rails which modifies an ActiveRecord.  Naturally, if the user reloads the page, we'll attempt to repeat the modification, which fails.
I want to redirect the URL that the user will "reload" (using the browser "Reload current page" button).
I want to reload using the same controller, same id, different action (not "update" but "edit")
Thanks.

Added update method

```
  # PUT /machines/<uuid> - a catch-all path for machine and channel modifications

  def update

    puts "machines:update #{params.to_s}" if @@debug_machines
    @id = params[:id]
    @machine = Machine.find_by_uuid(@id)

    puts "machines:update #{@machine.to_s_full}" if @@debug_machines

    session[:machine_id] = @id

    if params[:delete_channel]
      first = params[:delete_channel].keys.first.to_i
      puts "machines:update delete_channel #{first.to_s}" if @@debug_machines
      last = @machine.last_light_index(first)
      if last
        last.downto(first) do |i|
          @machine.channels.delete(@machine.channels[i])
        end
      else
        @machine.channels.delete(@machine.channels[first])if @machine.channels[first]
      end

    elsif params[:delete_filter]
      i = params[:delete_filter].keys.first.to_i
      puts "machines:update delete_filter  #{i.to_s}" if @@debug_machines
      channel = @machine.channels[i]
      puts "machines:update delete_filter  #{channel.to_s}" if @@debug_machines
      @machine.channels.delete(channels) if channel

    elsif params[:add_filter]
      i = @machine.last_light_index(params[:add_filter].keys.first.to_i)
      puts "machines:update add_filter channel #{i.to_s}" if @@debug_machines
      light = @machine.channels[i].light
      puts "machines:update add_filter light #{light.to_s}" if @@debug_machines
      @machine.channels.insert(i + 1, Channel.new(:light => light))


    elsif params[:commit]

... lots more similar stuff here ...

    end

    puts "machines:update after update #{@machine.to_s_full}" if @@debug_machines

    render :action => :edit
  end
```

Comment: Just for clarification, can your post your Controller#update method?

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as

```
redirect_to :action => :edit
```

Comment: The action already redirects to :action => edit, so I don't understand the answer.

Comment: It does not redirect to action `:edit`, it just renders its view. These are two different things.